# SFTP adapter on receive location not picking up files without extensions

Tags: adapter, sftp, biztalk

I have on my receive location an SFTP adapter that should pick up files that contain no visible extension. As such I have set my file mask to *.*

[image]

I've previously been able to pick up the same kind of files using a FILE adapter. The receive location is enabled and the host instance is running.

This is how a file is displayed on the SFTP:
[image]

I receive no warnings or errors in my event log. What could be the cause for this?

Comment: Well technically speaking, a file without an extension does not match *.* because it doesn't have a period in it.   What happens if you change the file mask to just * ?